# How can I upload zip file on HTML link , By shell script or terminal

Tags: file-sharing

My zip file is on my desktop. location (`/home/User/Desktop/example.zip`)  I want to upload that file on [this](http://example.com:8080/ContentZipUpload/contentZipUpload.jsp) by terminal or shell script. Is there is any solution?

Here is my destination

[image]

Comment: Please update your first link. It's not working.

Comment: It is example. I want to upload zip files on  multiple links. by script or terminal